# Algorithms of steganography

Tags: steganography, visual-cryptography

Recently I'm working on **steganography** and I want to know that what are the main **steganography algorithms and how they work.**
I'll be happy if you help me.
thanks.

Comment: I believe steganography is not cryptography, and also you asked for sources and "best platform for testing" which I believe is off topic. So IMO we are not ones to ask.

Comment: @axapaxa You're right, I edited my question but I just want to know how different steganography algorithms work.

Comment: I'm not sure if steganography is on-topic in crypto, but I guess since we have tag for it, it must be :P (but we also have tags for programming languages so...).

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi, These books may be helpful for you. Investigator's_Guide to Steganography, and Information Hiding (Techniques for Steganography And Watermarking).

Comment: @axapaxa I think it is on-topic. I saw a lot of topics related to steganography. anyway, thank you.

Comment: IMHO a quite recent good book is: J. Fridrich, Steganography in Digital Media, Cambridge 2010. Browse some threads on stego of this forum to see whether there are some infomations relevant to the special section of stego that you are currently working on.

Comment: Discrete Fourier Transform in StegoSec searches for nonuniformity based on BPP, to share what I know.  The engineer didn't go into specifics because StegoSec is proprietary, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: Strictly speaking, stegonography is a form of crypto.  Think Roman era wax tablets with hidden texts written underneath as an example.  This assumes you're doing "proper" stego.  With any scheme, doing it wrong might mean you aren't really doing it.

Comment: DTFT in StegoSec.  Apologies.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: @floorcat Thank you for all the things you told me and for your help.

Comment: No problem, my pleasure.  Good luck in your research.  When you have clear and specific questions about a steg algo it most likely wouldn't be put on hold.  Review the FAQ for how to write good questions to see what is expected.